# ¿como puedo pausar un metodo para que permita que termine otro en android studio /java?

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

tengo el metodo `comprobarUsuario` que consulta en la base de datos mysql si existe los datos que le estoy mandando, y me devuelve un 1 o 0 dependiendo del caso, tambien tengo el metodo `comprobarUsuarioP` cada vez que yo llame el metodo me devuelve un true o un false de la respuesta del metodo `comprobarUsuario`, lo tengo asi porque no consegui la manera de colocar al metodo `comprobarUsuario`como boolean y me retornara el true o false, el asunto final es que el metodo `comprobarUsuarioP` retorna el valor antes de que el metodo `comprobarUsuario` termine de ejecutarse

```
private void comprobarUsuario(String url){

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    String ob = "IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `loginusuario` WHERE `idusuario`='" + id.getText() + "' and `contrasena`='" + contra.getText() + "'), '1', '0')";
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (jsonObject.getString(ob).equals("1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        setComp(true);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error de conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

este es el metodo que llama al anterior

```
private boolean comprobarUsuarioP(String url){
    comprobarUsuario(url);
    return isComp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer que duerma por "x" segundos y luego ejecute la siguiente linea de código: así le darás tiempo de traer la información de la base de datos

```
private boolean comprobarUsuarioP(String url){
comprobarUsuario(url);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {   
 boolean variable_auxiliar = isComp();
}}, 3000);
return variable_auxiliar;
}
```

El `new Handler().postDelayed` duerme por 3 segundos: `}}, 3000);` y luego continua con el resto del codigo que esta dentro o sea : `boolean variable_auxiliar = isComp();` y luego `return variable_auxiliar;`